# Passing parameter to a timer interval

Tags: c#, timer

Maybe the answer to my question is obvious for a lot of you but It's a real pain for me.

I'm trying to pass parameter into the interval of my timer which type is a double, but it is always compiled as 0.

Thanks for your answers.

```
aTimer.Interval = 1000; // works like a charm

double doubleTypeVariable = 1000;
aTimer.Interval = doubleTypeVariable; // get 0 instead, as an interval value
```

Comment: What is the *full* type of `aTimer`?

Comment: System.Timers.Timer aTimer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();

Comment: When you debug, at the point directly after aTimer.Interval = doubleTypeVariable; are you saying that aTimer.Interval is 0?

Comment: When I took the following code and debugged I could see that Interval was correctly set to 1000: var aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            double doubleTypeVariable = 1000;
            aTimer.Interval = doubleTypeVariable;

Comment: Looking at one of your other comments can you confirm when debugging what value hmiData.hmiVarSynch["AttenteAg1"].ToString() is?

Comment: hmiData.hmiVarSynch["AttenteAg1"] is a HashTable element containing a type Double wich is in my case a value in milliseconds. Adding  ToString() returns the string value so I can convert it safely to Int32 or double. I think The Convert.To... works for an object without passing by the string value, It was just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing in the variable when you initiate your timer?

`double doubleTypeVariable = 1000;
System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(doubleTypeVariable);`

when I tested that, `aTimer.Interval`  equals 1000

Comment: It's an alternative, yes, but how does it answer his question?

Comment: though I tested it the same method that you started with and `aTimer.interval` still equalled 1000

Comment: @Matt I tried but same problem. There is a solution but i think it is smelly especially that i have a lot of cases where i use this kind of timer. I make a timer with true autoreset and interval like 1000 then inside the delegate I decrement the variable and check if it is = 0.